# RCM better than Nested dissection? (For FEM discretizations in 2D and 3D)

Tags: finite-element, matrix, linear-solver, sparse-matrix

I realize this might be a too general question but here goes nothing:

I am trying different re-ordering strategies and checking the fill-in of $A=LU$.

I have 2D ($p=1$, $h=1/40$ on $\Omega = [-1,1]^2$) discretizations of the Helmholtz equation and I was genuinely surprised to see Reverse Cuthill-McKee (RCM) outperform Nested dissection in all cases that I tried out.

Now, I was left in the belief that Nested dissection is state of the art. What am I missing? Does the strength of Nested Dissection lie in the hierarchical elimination using multifrontal methods? Is it 2D vs 3D? Or is RCM actually better?

I am grateful for any tips/pointers/directions and answers :)

Comment: How are you measuring fill-in? What do you mean when you say "outperform"?

Comment: I am simply checking the number of non-zero entries in the factors $L$ and $U$. It seems to me that nested dissection actually concentrates the fill-in to some regions, rather than reduce it.

Comment: Neither of them are guaranteed to reduce the bandwidth of the matrix (i.e. there are counter-examples). Using the bandwidth as the measure of fill-in (since L and U will have non-zeros only inside the band), we can say that neither of them has a theoretical edge over the other. However, in my experience, for FEM matrices, nested dissection hardly reduces the bandwidth while RCM generally reduces it.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. The goal with nested dissection seems to be to generate an arrowhead shape, which concentrates the fill-in near the end of the matrix so I would not expect it to reduce bandwidth. Is it possible that perhaps measuring fill-in using the $LU$ factors is the wrong approach?

Comment: What is RCM? Reverse Cuthill-McKee? You might want to explain the acronym in the question.

Comment: good point, I clarified it

Answer (score 3):

This landmark [paper](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0710032?journalCode=sjnaam) by George proves that a nested dissection ordering of a regular,
four-node element, finite element mesh produces minimum fill-in.

Although it is straightforward to produce such an ordering by inspection,
the graph algorithms that attempt to do this for a general sparse
structure only approximate this ordering.

Assuming you are obtaining your nested dissection ordering by
one of these algorithms, I suggested you take a look for small
meshes and see how close it comes to the true nested dissection ordering.

Comment: Thank you for this comment! I was aware of the paper but I had somehow forgotten that there was this proof. In fact, that is probably why I was left in this impression. My algorithm is very similar to the ones in the paper as it is based on geometric considerations but it seems that already adding a boundary will result in a loss of the fill-in minimizing property.

Comment: in fact, it seems that nested dissection is useful beyond minimising fill-in, as it also allows to manage the fill-in (Such as in multifrontal methods). Is this correct?